# Angular.js - Understanding what statements can go in an ng-class query

Tags: angularjs

The Angular docs are really sparse on what is acceptable in an "expression" within a conditional `ng-class`.

For example, I'm running an `ng-repeat` over a list:

```
<ul class="clothes">
  <li ng-repeat="piece in clothes | filter:query">
    {{piece.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

On every third `<li>` element I'd like to add a class of "third". Can this be done using `ng-class` with something like `ng-class="{third : li:nth-child(3)}"` or similar?

Side-note, is there a general reference somewhere that defines and gives examples of what can be used in an Angular expression? There's some really basic stuff that I can do with vanilla Javascript/css but I can't work out how to cram it into Angular!

Comment: Here is some documentation on angular expressions. http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression

Comment: So is the best way to do this to create an angular method and call that? I read that part of the docs before asking but I don't really know the best way to approach this problem/can't find examples of anything similar.

Comment: Yes, my experience is that if your condition is not very simple, the best thing is to create a function that returns true/false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create an expression that evaluates to true or false, a bit similar to Javascript expressions but with some differences, you can read about it [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression).

```
<ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="{third: !(($index+1)%3) && !$first }">{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

Here is a [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/iwewub/5/edit).

In my code I am telling ng-class to add the class 'third' when ($index+1)%3 is zero and it is not the $first list item ($index, $first and $last are created by ng-repeat).

Comment: Ah, this is perfect, thank you. I didn't realise that ng-repeat passed on $index, $first and $last, that's very handy to know for future reference. Thanks for explaining that in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use css instead of angular for the styling, you can use the css nth selector

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

li:nth-child(3n+3)
{
background:#ff0000;
}

Comment: This would work in most cases, but would it allow for Angular's reflow? (e.g. if the app refreshed the list and the 3rd item was no longer 3rd would the same rules apply?)

Comment: i believe it would, because the browser is re-rendering. probably have to put it to the test however on different devices/browsers